# Symlink for /home/

Tags: boot, lubuntu, home-directory, symbolic-link

By installing Windows 8.1 I removed whole linux partition (33GB) including swap part (sorry for my stupidity)... But I had my whole /home/ folder on other partition. I installed lubuntu again. How to get rid of current home and connect my previously created /home/ ?

My current disk and boot info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6605992/
/Home/ Partition that I want to link have size ~149-160GB. Please send me terminal commands to connect /home/ back.
I'm not experienced linux user and I'm using it only for few days. Please send me terminal commands to do that based on the paste that I added above

Comment: There is a complete guide of how to move your existing `/home` folder into a new partition. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving You can follow these steps except for copying the contents of your Lubuntu (new) `/home` to the old partition `/home`. **Do backup everythig before trying it.**

Answer (score 0):

OK, if I understand your question and paste data, your good 'home' partition is /dev/sdb7, and you want that mounted as /home on your root linux partition, which is /dev/sda6.

You can test this by booting into linux normally, and doing

```
     #sudo mount /dev/sdb7 /mnt
```

to see if the contents are your home directory.

You can mount /dev/sdb7 over your current /home right now via /etc/fstab by adding this entry:

```
      /dev/sdb7  /home    ext4    defaults   0  2
```

Do

```
      #sudo <your text editor here> /etc/fstab
```

add the entry to the end, and then reboot.

Later, you can run without this mount and clear out the space in the /home directory that is there now.